# Unable to open WD 1T HD

Tags: external-disk

Running Apple OS Big Sur 11.3.1.   Warranty on external HD expired March of 2021.  As of April 24th no backups have been made.  It shows in Finder preferences under USB, but not on the desktop, terminal, or disk utility.  The HD is running constantly.  Can not diagnose with WD Utility app and can not erase.  Starts, freezes up midway.

Any recommendations, or just replace with a new SSD?

5/12/21  I did try this drive with a different cable and a different computer and still could not get the drive to show.  The drive looks like it is formatted incorrectly as exFAT.  The drive has worked for the past three years without a problem.  Would like to erase and reformat in APFS, but can not find a way to do so.

Comment: Can you change the USB cable? Have try this disk on an another Mac?

Comment: What is the file system on the external HDD?